# How to add space between three images in a row in a grid view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have retrieved three images from a database and displayed them in a Grid View. The problem is that I am not able to get space between all three images.

It's not working even if I give a cell spacing value. Here is the image:

[image: Image of rows of images between which I want space between the images]

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Home" Runat="Server">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="packid" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="None">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="packid" HeaderText="packid" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="packid" ItemStyle-Width="95px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="packname" HeaderText="packname" 
            SortExpression="packname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="categoryname" HeaderText="categoryname" 
            SortExpression="categoryname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="subcatname" HeaderText="subcatname" 
            SortExpression="subcatname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="packageprice" HeaderText="packageprice" 
            SortExpression="packageprice"/>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="pic1" SortExpression="pic1" ItemStyle-Width="80px">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pic1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="50px" 
                    ImageUrl='<%# Eval("pic1") %>' Width="80px" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="60px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="pic2" SortExpression="pic2" ItemStyle-Width="80px">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pic2") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="50px" 
                    ImageUrl='<%# Eval("pic2") %>' Width="80px" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="pic3" SortExpression="pic3" ItemStyle-Width="80px">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pic3") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" Height="50px" 
                    ImageUrl='<%# Eval("pic3") %>' Width="80px" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>



<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ToursandTravelsConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [packid], [packname], [categoryname], [subcatname], [packageprice], [pic1], [pic2], [pic3] FROM [package]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding little bit margin will solve your issue. Set cssClass of your images like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" CssClass="imgDist" Height="50px" 
                ImageUrl='<%# Eval("pic2") %>' Width="80px" />
```

and within your style do this:

```
<style>
    .imgDist {
        margin:5px;
    }
</style>
```

or instead of setting class, just add this, it will be applied to all the images.

```
<style>
    img {
        margin:5px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

write below code and check if its working or not

```
<asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" Height="50px" 
                    ImageUrl='<%# Eval("pic3") %>' Width="80px" style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px" />
```

Try this